# Message Bubble Custom Drawable

Tags: java, android, material-components-android, android-shapedrawable

I will share the image below that I want to develop my message bubble in Native Android[image: Have to make like this]

I have written some code in Custom Drawable XML please have a look and I will share the image what it looks like, first see the code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="55"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toDegrees="0">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#00A1E4" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item android:right="28dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#00A1E4" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

the above code looks like this [image: The Above code]

Please help me on how to make like the first image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ShapeAppearanceModel` to apply a custom `EdgeTreatment` to a widget for eaxmple a `CardView`:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        ...>

       <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
          android:id="@+id/cardview"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
          app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/..."/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Then you can apply a custom `ShapeAppearanceModel` using the builtin **`MarkerEdgeTreatment`** that draws an arrow on the edge given the radius of a circle. Something like:

```
    val markerEdgeTreatment = MarkerEdgeTreatment(cardview.radius)
    val offsetEdgeTreatment = OffsetEdgeTreatment(markerEdgeTreatment, 90f)

    cardview.setShapeAppearanceModel(
        cardview.getShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setRightEdge(offsetEdgeTreatment)
            .build()
    )
```

[image]

You can also customize the shape of the edge extending the `EdgeTreatment` and overriding the `getEdgePath` method.

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.2.0`** of the Material Components Library.